# Highcharts: How to plot a inverted columnrange along with a line chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, axis, multiple-axes

**[EDIT] - Resolved:** See final chart in the end.

**Infomation**

Some background first. I have a line chart that plots power produced by a facility in a very simple line chart. This facility has 5 machines producing this power. Sometimes, these machines have some problem or errors.

I would like to show these errors and for how long they have persisted, per machine, along with the power production chart.

**The errors chart**

Reading the Highcharts docs I realized that the best way to show that would be in a `columnrange`chart, inverting it to be a horizontal `columnrange`chart.

Here is an example ([jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/XjzFH/440/)):

- Obs: Consider the `[-6 .. 9 ]` axis as a `datetime` axis

[image: Chart 1]

This chart would be read like: Machine 0 had two errors: One from -6 to -1, and another one from 0 to 2, and so on.

**Where Am I now?**

So, now I tried to make this work together with a line chart. And this is where I can not make it work. My `columnrange`chart stays in the **vertical and not in the horizontal** and I can figure how to flip it.

Here is the current state: ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XjzFH/439/))

[image: Chart 2]

**Question**

Is there any way I can plot these two charts together?

**[EDIT] Answer**

Using @jlbriggs comment's idea, I could come up with the right chart ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XjzFH/443/)):

[image: Final Chart]

Comment: If you want the bars to be horizontal, you **have** to set `inverted: true` on the `chart` object.  In order to make a line chart work in this way, you would need to reverse your data - set the `x` values to the `y` values and vice-versa.

Comment: Yes, that work. Could you elaborate that as an answer so I can chose it as the right one ?